# Is there anything SE can do about email spam I received?

Tags: discussion, spam

I received the following in my inbox. I thought I'd report it for anything SE could do to address the issue.

My suspicion is "Not much;" it was sent to an email addy I don't remember providing to SE.

```
Delivered-To: christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.58.48 with SMTP id n16csp506679wjq;
        Tue, 4 Nov 2014 14:05:19 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.229.214.5 with SMTP id gy5mr9375158qcb.18.1415138717602;
        Tue, 04 Nov 2014 14:05:17 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <help@semaphorecorp.com>
Received: from mail.penguintopia.com (mail.penguintopia.com. [66.151.32.248])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 53si3055344qgi.52.2014.11.04.14.05.14
        for <christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 04 Nov 2014 14:05:14 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of help@semaphorecorp.com does not designate 66.151.32.248 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.151.32.248;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of help@semaphorecorp.com does not designate 66.151.32.248 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=help@semaphorecorp.com;
       dkim=neutral (no key for signature) header.i=@
Received: from mail.penguintopia.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id B0D1A9BBA
    for <christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com>; Tue,  4 Nov 2014 22:05:13 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=semaphorecorp.com;
    s=mail; t=1415138713;
    bh=rzTFWfCvE5fo5rcEzToE57JEBEQY5Gw+CyTqN0hqX58=;
    h=Date:To:From:Subject;
    b=N24Tq9etCMtm4int1kzvjkH8q/PcDxoQTdg1PoFLxxapc9/k+278J01uhcdK7JZiE
     dVNGpGL7FJMTjxffWMZIBdfilkHWBZj+MAx7HsH4mnRasq2tC7zXSRvhaVOzs8DXUT
     F4SM1vmCoz6n/aOABalSQdFqZQtxSqRKv4hraXeM=
Received: by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id 6AB75A274; Tue,  4 Nov 2014 22:05:13 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=semaphorecorp.com;
    s=mail; t=1415138713;
    bh=rzTFWfCvE5fo5rcEzToE57JEBEQY5Gw+CyTqN0hqX58=;
    h=Date:To:From:Subject;
    b=N24Tq9etCMtm4int1kzvjkH8q/PcDxoQTdg1PoFLxxapc9/k+278J01uhcdK7JZiE
     dVNGpGL7FJMTjxffWMZIBdfilkHWBZj+MAx7HsH4mnRasq2tC7zXSRvhaVOzs8DXUT
     F4SM1vmCoz6n/aOABalSQdFqZQtxSqRKv4hraXeM=
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on
    mail.penguintopia.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=0.8 required=1.4 tests=BAYES_50 autolearn=ham
    version=3.3.1
X-Spam-ASN:  
Received: from mail-fs3.redshift.com (mail9.redshift.com [216.228.2.145])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 02EEC9BBA
    for <cjsh@cjshayward.com>; Tue,  4 Nov 2014 22:05:10 +0000 (UTC)
Received: (qmail 73457 invoked by uid 89); 4 Nov 2014 22:05:08 -0000
Received: from 216-228-19-124-static.dsl.redshift.com (HELO Monterey-HP.semaphorecorp.com) (mgdsl@216.228.19.124)
  by mail9.redshift.com with AES256-SHA encrypted SMTP; 4 Nov 2014 14:05:08 -0800
Message-Id: <7.0.1.0.1.20141104140502.01dd9f00@semaphorecorp.com>
Message-Id: <7.0.1.0.1.20141104135148.01dd99e0@semaphorecorp.com>
X-Mailer: QUALCOMM Windows Eudora Version 7.0.1.0
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 14:05:08 -0800
To: cjsh@cjshayward.com
From: Semaphore Corporation <help@semaphorecorp.com>
Subject: stackoverflow (online address correction)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"; format=flowed
X-Virus-Scanned: ClamAV using ClamSMTP [Tue Nov  4 22:05:13 2014 +0000 (UTC)]

We read your posting on stackoverflow.
We just expanded our online address correction servers
and we think you'll find them useful.  Simply reply to get
your password and 100 megabytes of I/O, while supplies last.

Besides the usual ZIP+4, DPV, LACSLink and SuiteLink
databases for CASS, you can use the full complement of our
ZP4 software and data:  DirectDPV, RDI, eLot, geocoding,
batch processing, database browsing and exports, form 3553
generation, interactive forward and reverse lookups,
dozens of tools that include source, and a full API for your
own code.  You'll have complete access to our remote servers
to empower your processing like never before.
```

Addition after second UCE:

**My contact page is at [CJSHayward.com/contact](https://CJSHayward.com/contact/) and states explicitly: "Please do not send spam".** If the private email is spam when someone said, "Please do not send spam", it *may* be SE's concern that SE was used in the process of sending the spam. I don't want to give a final answer, but it may be SE's concern if SE is used to send UCE against clearly expressed wishes.

Second UCE received:

```
Delivered-To: christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.58.48 with SMTP id n16csp635869wjq;
        Wed, 5 Nov 2014 10:15:13 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.236.10.45 with SMTP id 33mr5954516yhu.154.1415211312968;
        Wed, 05 Nov 2014 10:15:12 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <help@semaphorecorp.com>
Received: from mail.penguintopia.com (mail.penguintopia.com. [66.151.32.248])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t3si3619256yhp.31.2014.11.05.10.15.12
        for <christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 05 Nov 2014 10:15:12 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of help@semaphorecorp.com does not designate 66.151.32.248 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.151.32.248;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of help@semaphorecorp.com does not designate 66.151.32.248 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=help@semaphorecorp.com;
       dkim=neutral (no key for signature) header.i=@
Received: from mail.penguintopia.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6FC9C9DEA
    for <christos.jonathan.hayward@gmail.com>; Wed,  5 Nov 2014 18:15:11 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=semaphorecorp.com;
    s=mail; t=1415211311;
    bh=k2WUWOEl8NSb3rwT3HFytkORoo9fBUOfl/CQ/+zXoSA=;
    h=Date:To:From:Subject;
    b=Ez8ZwOS08lG49hl7cg7oPQU8gKCj9tCUxlq2vuR588WtDYeqW0lct/Ho2GDZuBZ+j
     cl09adlaHegj1zReRcIS+oAmkO9XNcqSxpa4rK86zBofn4n8Ae8KakeiGrn5d1rc33
     QvYg1WQpBcDZdcA62dPGwPxr9hDg30wo8oJSw5MA=
Received: by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id 3A7CE9E09; Wed,  5 Nov 2014 18:15:11 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=semaphorecorp.com;
    s=mail; t=1415211311;
    bh=k2WUWOEl8NSb3rwT3HFytkORoo9fBUOfl/CQ/+zXoSA=;
    h=Date:To:From:Subject;
    b=Ez8ZwOS08lG49hl7cg7oPQU8gKCj9tCUxlq2vuR588WtDYeqW0lct/Ho2GDZuBZ+j
     cl09adlaHegj1zReRcIS+oAmkO9XNcqSxpa4rK86zBofn4n8Ae8KakeiGrn5d1rc33
     QvYg1WQpBcDZdcA62dPGwPxr9hDg30wo8oJSw5MA=
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on
    mail.penguintopia.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9 required=1.4 tests=BAYES_00 autolearn=ham
    version=3.3.1
X-Spam-ASN:  
Received: from mail-fs3.redshift.com (mail9.redshift.com [216.228.2.145])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail.penguintopia.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 89DA19DEA
    for <cjsh@cjshayward.com>; Wed,  5 Nov 2014 18:15:03 +0000 (UTC)
Received: (qmail 34915 invoked by uid 89); 5 Nov 2014 18:13:11 -0000
Received: from 216-228-19-124-static.dsl.redshift.com (HELO Monterey-HP.semaphorecorp.com) (mgdsl@216.228.19.124)
  by mail9.redshift.com with AES256-SHA encrypted SMTP; 5 Nov 2014 10:13:11 -0800
Message-Id: <7.0.1.0.1.20141105100654.01c05468@semaphorecorp.com>
Disposition-Notification-To: <help@semaphorecorp.com>
X-Mailer: QUALCOMM Windows Eudora Version 7.0.1.0
Date: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 10:13:09 -0800
To: cjsh@cjshayward.com
From: Semaphore Corporation <help@semaphorecorp.com>
Subject: we really DID see your stackoverflow Tiger/street address
  posting
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"; format=flowed
X-Virus-Scanned: ClamAV using ClamSMTP [Wed Nov  5 18:15:11 2014 +0000 (UTC)]

we thought we might be helping, not spamming.
since you asked about tiger data
and you can do free lookups/conversions/exports on our servers,
we offered you to try it.
since se hates posting commercial plugs,
we went from your question to your profile to your web site to your 
contact email and sent you the email.
ironically, you plugged it for us! (although it won't get much 
attention on meta...)
```

Comment: "I read your posting on stackoverflow" is an effective pick-up line, even spammers know it. Perhaps they harvested emails elsewhere (something IT related) and used SO just for that opening line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an email sent via the user's personal contact page and requests made on the user's personal web site, and is outside the scope and control of SE.

Comment: "Delivered-To:"/"To:" now everyone (even google) knows your email...

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately, no. It's not coming from us, and we aren't releasing your email address in any way. That's about the extent of things we can influence.

I gotta agree with [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243057/is-there-anything-se-can-do-about-this-spam#comment794515_243057): "We read your posting on stackoverflow" is so generic that we can only take it as a sign that we've "made it".

Sorry.

Comment: could you reread the (expanded) basenote and maybe the answers? This person found me (and how to contact me) through StackOverflow. I wonder if your legal counsel could add TOS-like warnings about spamming/harassing people using SE if they find someone through SE and use SE to look up how to contact the party. Notwithstanding that the commercial offering was "lookups/conversions/exports", the spammer needed SE to identify what was once a PR5 website.

Comment: (And I want to be accessible through appropriate means; I do not wish to hold visitors hostage by punishing many welcome visitors for the actions of a few spammers.)

Comment: @JonathanHayward I am not a lawyer, so I'm not sure what TOS-type stuff is even feasible here. My take on this is that if you make your contact info public, you should expect that people will contact you, sometimes about things you don't care about.

Comment: From the bottom of SE's pages: "tour help blog chat data legal privacy policy work here advertising info mobile contact us feedback": Legal points to TOS: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: @JonathanHayward I know we have a TOS document.

Answer (score 8):

I sent JonathanHayward the "spam", although I thought I was helping.
I saw his posting about Tiger/street conversions, so I offered a big chunk of free lookups/conversions/exports on our servers.  Since SE hates posting commercial plugs, I went from his question to his profile to his web site to his contact email and sent him the email.  Ironically, he posted the plug for us! (Although it probably won't get much attention here on meta...)

Comment: Just because shouting your advertisement out loud is not okay, it doesn't mean you should be telling people privately.

Comment: @JanDvorak Even though I disagree with the tactics here, if somebody wants to click through to a public web site, find publicly posted contact info, and send a private email, it's none of our business, really. And it is nice to see somebody own up to it with an explanation.

Comment: @JasonC, please see the revised and expanded post about second UCE in violation of wishes expressed on the contact page.

Comment: @Jon By the time I clicked through your posting, then your profile, then your home page, then your contact page, I was just quickly scanning for an email link and not paying attention to your other site content at all.  I saw your big bold email address and clicked it, and literally read nothing else at your site, especially the "no spam" request (which might seem "clearly expressed" to you but I didn't notice it at all).  My frame of mind was to offer a free tool you might find useful for your original problem.  I apologize that it's caused you so much irritation.

Comment: @JonathanHayward I definitely feel you, but, we've now established the contact route, and what is or is not on your personal contact page, and whether or not somebody reads and honors that info, are not topics for meta (well, good for meta.cjshayward.com, maybe). :)